# recursive sequence - Which approach can I take to solve this equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Having this recurrence relation 

$a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 4·3^n$ 
$a_1 = 36$
$a_0 = 0$

How can I solve this?
I tried by characteristics roots and got stuck:

*making $a_n=r^n$
$r^n =  5r^{n-1} - 6r^{n-2} - 4·3^n$

*dividing by $r^{n-2}$ and equating to zero got:
$r^2 + 6 - 5r - 4·3^2 = 0$

*solving the equation and getting the roots got an irrational root:
$= {-5+-\sqrt{145}\over2} $

I'm stuck there, 
How can I solve this with the irrational roots?
What other methods can I try?
Thanks

Comment: do you you mean "recursive"? (As the standard terminology)

Comment: @StretchManiac In the world of computer science, it's called a "recurrence relation". In the world of mathematics, I believe it's called a "recursive sequence".

Comment: thanks I edited the question

Comment: You should use $0$ instead $4\cdot 3^n$ in characteristic equation. $4\cdot 3^n$ should be used for partial solution separately.

Comment: It seems for me the parital solution is $12\cdot n\cdot 3^n$

Answer (score 1):

The sequence in question is
\begin{align}
a_{n+2} - 5 a_{n+1} + 6 a_{n} = 4 \cdot 3^{n+2}
\end{align}
where $a_{0} = 0$ and $a_{1} = 36$. Considering the primary equation $a_{n+2} - 5 a_{n+1} + 6 a_{n} =0$ for which, by taking $a_{n} \approx r^{n}$, leads to $(r-2)(r-3)= 0$ and hence $a_{n} = A 2^{n} + B 3^{n}$. Now for the particular solution it is noticed that the term $3^{n}$ appears in the homogenous solution and particular. Due to this then take $C \, 3^{n} n$ as the particular solution. From this the general form is now
\begin{align}
a_{n} = A 2^{n} + B 3^{n} + C 3^{n} n. 
\end{align}
Applying the initial condition $a_{0} = 0$ it is seen that $B = -A$ and 
\begin{align}
a_{n} = A(2^{n} - 3^{n}) + C 3^{n} n.
\end{align}
Applying this solution to the equation in question it is determined that $C = 12$ and leads to
\begin{align}
a_{n} = A(2^{n} - 3^{n} ) + 4 \cdot 3^{n+1} \cdot n.
\end{align}
Applying the condition $a_{1} = 36$ leads to $A = 0$ and hence $a_{n} = 4 \cdot 3^{n+1} \cdot n$.

Comment: What's the name if this technique? why are you equating to $4·3^n$? Thanks for your help

Comment: @luisc29 typo corrected.